# SQL Server: assigning dynamic SQL query to variable and executing

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I have a scenario where I have to execute a dynamic SQL query based on table name.

For example i have a table X

```
|**table name**|  **Query**                                               |
|--------------|------------------------------------------------------------|
| A            |select ' +@somevariable1+ ' from '+@servername+ @table_name |
```

So my query looks like

```
Set @sql = (select query from X where table name =@table_name)   
Exec @sql
```

Here the `exec @sql` is not working. Any ideas on how to exec this dynamic SQL query?

Comment: Sorry my table structure got messed up and I am not sure how to correct it

Comment: use `control-k` or add 4 space to code format

Comment: You are missing a connector between "table" and "name".

Comment: `Set @sql = 'select something from some table'` is the basic of it. @sql is a string aka varchar so you have to pass it what you would execute. To concat table names as parameters use `set @sql = 'select something from ' + @table`

Comment: I think you just simply need to put the variable into **parenthesis**: `EXEC (@sql); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to like this, Actually you need execute dynamic script twice.
First time to get the really SQL script, then excute the script that generated before, For example:

```
DECLARE @servername NVARCHAR(100)='master.dbo.',@table_name Nvarchar(100)='spt_values',@somevariable1 NVARCHAR(100)='number'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max),@query NVARCHAR(max)
;WITH X(TableName,Query)AS(
        SELECT 'A',  '''SELECT top 5 '' +@somevariable1+ '' from ''+@servername+ @table_name+'' WHERE type=''''p''''''' 
)
SELECT @query=X.Query FROM X WHERE X.TableName='A'

SET @query=N'set @sql=(select '+@query+N')'
exec sp_executesql @query,N'@sql nvarchar(max) out,@servername NVARCHAR(100),@table_name varchar(100),@somevariable1 NVARCHAR(100)'
,@sql out,@servername ,@table_name,@somevariable1
PRINT @sql    
EXEC( @sql)
```

```
--Excute command result at first time:
SELECT top 5 number from master.dbo.spt_values WHERE type='p'
--- Execute below script:

number
-----------
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot Nolan. you saved lot of time for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need specify schema

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx

```
CREATE TABLE   
    [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ] table_name   
    ( { <column_definition> } [ ,...n ] )   
[ ; ]
```

So your query shoule be:

```
'select ' + @somevariable1 + ' from ' + @servername + '.[dbo].' + @table_name
```

Comment: Thanks Juan. But my question is not about the syntax of the query. The syntax is fine and its working(sorry i didn't post the entire syntax here).
My question is :
set @sql = some dynamic query

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: Thanks Juan for looking into this and editing the format. Sorry I couldn't explain it properly.